# Format Informatica API Response

Tags: rest, informatica, informatica-cloud

I have a connection to Census.gov API via Informatica. The connection works fine and I am able to place the connection in a process and write it to a flat file on a local directory. The issue is that the format is unreadable as a source by Informatica. The file has fields wrapped in brackets and one field has commas, so I will need to wrap them in quotation marks. Is there a way to edit the flat file once it has written or a way to set up the API so I can specify a format?

Inside Informatica I am handling the response as an attachment.

Comment: you can use shell script to modify a file after downloading

Comment: Are you using Application Integration or Data Integration tool? You should be able to modify the data yet even before writing to the file.

Comment: Application integration. When I look at the return it has brackets I need to remove. I am trying to work this in the output tab in the service connector
The full request is:
https://api.census.gov/data/2020/acs/acs5/profile?get=NAME,DP05_0001E,DP05_0065PE,DP05_0065E,DP05_0071PE,DP05_0071E,DP05_0066PE,DP05_0066E,DP05_0067PE,DP05_0067E,DP05_0068PE,DP05_0068E,DP05_0064PE,DP05_0064E,DP05_0069PE,DP05_0069E,DP05_0077PE,DP05_0077E,DP05_0038PE,DP05_0038E,DP05_0039PE,DP05_0039E,DP05_0044PE,DP05_0044E,DP05_0052PE,DP05_0052E,DP05_0057PE,DP05_0057E,DP05_0035PE,DP05_0035E&in=state:01&for=tract%3A%2A

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a batch file that performs a replace on the characters I need to remove in order to treat the file as a CSV